# Converting *.mis, *fin to *txt file

Tags: vb6

How to convert the text file through vb6 code.

Having filename like clock.fin, time.mis, date.fin, so on...,

I want to give as clock.txt, time.txt, date.txt through code.

Comment: do you want to change a file extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename a file simply by:

```
Name "c:\xxx.fin" As "c:\xxx.txt"
```

There is no need to take the long way using the FSO.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rename a file using vb6 you can do it as follows:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set file = fso.GetFile("c:\oldName.txt") 
file.name = "newName.txt" 
Set file = nothing 
Set fso = nothing
```

Or :

```
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
 fso.MoveFile "c:\oldname.txt", "c:\newname.txt" 
 Set fso = Nothing
```

**Updated:**

You can use FileSystemObject.GetExtensionName method to get the extension of a path (file) then you can replace it by "txt"